# Typescript notation to C# conversion for object

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have my angular2 program which makes http posts just fine for other actions, but this one is driving me crazy.

Here's the typescript DTO:

```
export class NutritionixSearchRequest
{
  appId: string;
  appKey: string;
  query: string;
  fields: string[];
  sort: {};
  filters: {};
}
```

When I fill this and serialize it, I get a string similar to this:

```
        {"appId":"app_id","appKey":"app_key","query":"taco bell",
"fields":"item_name","brand_name","nf_calories","nf_serving_size_qty","nf_serving_size_unit"],
    "sort":{"field":"_score","order":"desc"},"filters":{"item_type":2}}
```

If I feed this string to fiddler as the body of the post request, and send to the company's api directly, it works.  If I send the request to my api which then calls the company's api, the dto is not the same.

I've tried both versions of my api DTO's (shown below) to no avail.  The first returns and object with sorts/filters set to null.  The second returns the items with "{{" as shown in the image.
[image: Locals showing object]

this version doesn't work at all and I'm calling the company's api the same. Here's the serialized object from webapi 2:

```
    {"appId":"app_id","appKey":"app_key","query":"taco bell",
"fields":"item_name","brand_name","nf_calories","nf_serving_size_qty","nf_serving_size_unit"],
"sort":[[[]],[[]]],"filters":[[[]]]}
```

Here's the dto's:

```
 public class NutritionixSearchRequestDto
 {
    public string appId { get; set; }
    public string appKey { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> fields { get; set; }
    public ICollection<object> sort { get; set; }
    public ICollection<object> filters { get; set; }
 }

public class NutritionixSearchRequestDto
    {
        public string appId { get; set; }
        public string appKey { get; set; }
        public string query { get; set; }
        public ICollection<string> fields { get; set; }
        public object sort { get; set; }
        public object filters { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the webapi method:

```
[Route("nxqlSearch")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> nxqlSearch([FromBody] NutritionixSearchRequestDto nsrd)
{
   JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   NutritionixSearchDto nsr = new NutritionixSearchDto();

   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var searchQuery = oJS.Serialize(nsrd);
      searchQuery.Replace("app_id", appId).Replace("app_key", appKey);
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri + "/search");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(baseUri + "/search"), searchQuery);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         var results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
         nsr = oJS.Deserialize<NutritionixSearchDto>(results.ToString());
      }
   }

   return Ok(nsr);
}
```